# Syntax error on token "if", int expected, java

Tags: java

Ничего не помогает. Без лишних слов:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static int random(int min,int max) {
    java.util.Random randomClass = new java.util.Random();
    int generatedInteger = randomClass.nextInt(max - min) + min;
    return generatedInteger;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random generator = new Random(100); 
    int x = random(50, 100);
    int y = random(50, 100);
    int z = x + y;
    System.out.print(x + " + ");
    System.out.println(y);
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    if a = z; {
        return a;   
        }
    int a = scanner.nextInt();

        }
    }
}
```

Ошибка в 10, 18 и 21 строке

Comment: `if a = z; {
        return a;   
        }` - что это?

Comment: незаконченный код

Comment: ну тогда что ты от компилятора хочешь? чтоб он на эту невнятность не ругался?

Comment: я все делал и с return и без него

Comment: он на a ругается

Comment: всё - что? и причем тут return и без него? и зачем там return вообще?

Comment: смотрел решения проблем, решил добавить - не исправилось

Comment: знаешь как пишется `if` ?

Comment: все - все способы решения, которые смог откопать

Comment: да аааааааааааа

Comment: ну и `if` надо писать после `int a = scanner.nextInt();`.... логично?

Answer (score 0):

Уберите запятую на 19 строке: у вас `if (a == z); {`, а должно быть `if (a == z) {`.

Ответ продублирован [отсюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/709321/%D0%92-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-java/709323#709323).
Не задавайте впредь, пожалуйста, повторяющиеся вопросы, на них редко кто будет обращать внимание. Если кто-то сможет или захочет, тот ответит сразу, либо чуть позже. Уважайте ruSO.

Comment: а зачем дублировать ответ из дубликата? и вообще зачем писать ответ а не закрыть как дубль? и вообще можно закрыть как опечатка

Comment: @АлексейШиманский ответил там, когда не видел этот вопрос