# Отчего возникает ошибка - Syntax error on token "else", delete this token

Tags: java, исключения

Строка 22, ошибка

> Syntax error on token "else", delete this token

Код:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static int random(int min,int max) {
        java.util.Random randomClass = new java.util.Random();
        int generatedInteger = randomClass.nextInt(max - min) + min;
        return generatedInteger;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Random generator = new Random(100); 

        int x = random(50, 100);
        int y = random(50, 100);

        int z = x + y;
        System.out.print(x + " + ");
        System.out.println(y);

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int a = scanner.nextInt();

        if (a == z); {
            System.out.println("Правильный ответ.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Неправильный ответ. Правильный ответ - " + z);         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Не надо повторять вопросы. Одна проблема - один вопрос. Дубль https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/709282/syntax-error-on-token-if-int-expected-java

Answer (score 3):

Уберите запятую на 19 строке: у вас `if (a == z); {`, а должно быть `if (a == z) {`.